# New-PnPTerm : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I want to create a new term using PnP for our sharepoint online tenant, so i tried this PnP script:-

```
PS C:\Windows> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://****-admin.sharepoint.com
PS C:\Windows> New-PnPTerm -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" -Name "Active IT" -Id 53385e78-e4c3-4f26-baac-bf7c832ec7d2
```

But i got this error:-

> New-PnPTerm : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index At line:1 char:1
>   + New-PnPTerm -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" -Name "Active IT...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-PnPTerm], ServerException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Taxo    nomy.NewTerm

so can anyone advice on this?

I also tried to pass the `Lcid` (although i think i do not have to, if i want to use the defualt) + i reorder the parameters as mentioned on this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/new-pnpterm?view=sharepoint-ps, but i am still getting the same error:-

```
New-PnPTerm -Name "Active IT" -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers"  -Id "53385e78-e4c3-4f26-baac-bf7c832ec7d2" -Lcid "1033"
```

Comment: Are the ID just a random generated string? According to the documentation, this must be a valid GUID and not a string. If you really want that number, try convert it to a GUID and then create a new term. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e5039798-98f8-4861-a97b-bdc9c1c1acb2/converting-a-string-to-guid?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: @Christoffer the `-Id` is a GUID number i got from our on-premises farm, as i want the on-premsies term and the online term to have the same GUID..

Comment: @Christoffer also even if i remove the `-Id` as follow `New-PnPTerm -Name "Active IT" -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" `.. i will still get the same error `New-PnPTerm : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `TermSet` and `TermGroup` specified already exist in the Term Store.

This works for me if both are already present:

```
New-PnPTerm -Name "Active IT" -TermSet "T Group" -TermGroup "Customers" -Id "53385e78-e4c3-4f26-baac-bf7c832ec7d2" -Lcid "1033"
```

You can use the `New-PnPTermGroup` and `New-PnPTermSet` to create the term group and termset before creating the new term.

Comment: your script worked fine... and do you think there is any problem if we use an on-premises term GUID to add a new term inside SP online using the on-premises GUID? as in my case i want the on-premsies and online term to have the same GUID

Comment: I don’t see any reason that should be a problem. The GUID only has to be unique in the term store.

Comment: Please mention MANDATORY parameters "-TermGroup", "-id", "LCID". It should work

Answer (score 2):

You have to check, which languages are allowed in your Term store.

Replace your tenant name in the following URL and then open it in a browser:
https://*[yourTenantName]*-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/termStoreAdminCenter

In my case, the term store had only English (lcid 1033) set as default language and no additional Working language was defined.

When running the PowerShell, it automatically took lcid 1031 (German) as default, so it failed. When I tried setting manually lcid 1031, it still failed. When I set lcid manually to lcid 1033, the command succeeded, but that was not, what I wanted.

The solution was to got in the term store administration and add German as a working language. Afterwards, I was also able to run the command without setting lcid. It is also possible to change the default Term Store language afterwards.